# Cannot Authenticate Azure Ad users using an api with Bearer token .net core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get the sample mvc template that Visual Studio Gives you with Authentication. However when I call the API using a Bearer token I get the Sign in HTML as Response. How Can I get the application to accept browser based and token based at the same time? most of the examples I see are either API or View.  here is my current iteration of the Startup code:'

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
            .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
                "AzureADOpenID", "AzureADCookie", "AzureADBearer", "AzureADJwtBearer",
                "AzureAD");
            defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder =
                defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
        });
        services.AddMvc();
        //services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        //{
        //    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        //        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        //        .Build();
        //    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        //});
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Test Prjoect", Version = "v1" });
        });
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

and then I have `app.UseAuthentication();` and `app.UseAuthorization();` in the configure Section.

Comment: Seems to me that it's because you have interactive authentication as the default scheme. If you add a default forward selector on the interactive scheme, it can check if the call contains a Bearer token and change the default for that request.

Comment: sorry I am kinds new to this, is there a way to add multiple schemes? because when I change the default authentication scheme I break the user authentication through the browser.

Comment: Yes, you make one the default and then add a forward default selector on the default scheme that forwards the default choice to the other one based on some logic, like the presence of a header.

Comment: @Tacot Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: I was on vacation I havent had time to look into it